# Butterworth Filter Example Different in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to recreate the example third-order low-pass Butterworth filter from the Wikipedia page. It has the following diagram and frequency response plot. On the wikipedia page it gives the values as C2 = 4/3 F, R4 = 1 Ω, L1 = 3/2 H, and L3 = 1/2 H. Link to the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter. [image: wikipedia circuit diagram][image: expected frequency response]

I have recreated this in LTspice with unfortunately very different results. I tried this both with and without a voltage supply at Vin with the same results. I also tried using both linear and decade sweeps which also had the same output. I've changed the dotted line from phase to the delay to match the Wikipedia plot, but they clearly are not the same. [image: LTspice diagram] [image: LTspice plot]

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: With R1/(R1+R2)=1/11  Your attenuation starts near -21dB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia image is for a filter with \$\omega_c=1\ s^{-1}\$. That is, the horizontal axis is in radian frequency.

But LTSpice plots its output with the horizontal axis in Hz (cycles per second).

\$1\ s^{-1}\$ radian frequency is about 0.159 Hz, so it appears that your two plots do actually agree.

If you want to make the two plots look more alike, change the upper frequency in your LTSpice simulation to 0.796 Hz, equivalent to \$5\ s^{-1}\$ radian frequency.